# qmake and system variables - Linux vs. Windows

Tags: linux, windows, environment-variables, qmake

This is a follow up to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38394981/1559401) previous question of mine.

Here is the (simplified) location in that `qmake` script that causes problems (I'm currently testing only this particular library but I've also checked and the same issue is present with the others too):

```
VTK_API = ""

CONFIG(debug, debug|release) {
    message(Application will be built in DEBUG mode)
    VTK_API = $$(VTK_DBG_DIR)
}
else {
    message(Application will be built in RELEASE mode)
    VTK_API = $$(VTK_DIR)
}
```

I've moved my `qmake` project file to Linux to check how it's working there. And for my surprise the environment variables are not read properly that is when I output the value from the given variable it's empty. I've adjusted the paths for both versions of the library since I have a different naming of the respective environment variables (in `.bashrc`) that point at the location of its debug and release builds.

```
user@debian:~$ echo $VTK_DBG_DIR
/opt/vtk-dbg/lib
user@debian:~$ echo $VTK_DIR
/opt/vtk/lib
```

As you can see the variables are properly `echo`ed in my terminal. I also have to add that I start my `Qt Creator` from my `bash` terminal due to some other things that I want loaded along with the IDE so the case "Your variables are not read since Qt Creator doesn't read what's in your .bashrc" is not present here.

Any idea what's going on here? Is there a difference in the way the loading of environment variables works in `qmake` based on the operating system or am I missing something else here (an error in my script perhaps)?

Comment: What do you understand under "are not read properly"? What does `message($$VTK_API)` print after your `else` block?

Comment: Good point. I'll add this info. With "not read properly" I mean "empty".

Comment: Are you sure those are environment variables, that is, have you exported them?

Comment: Yes, I have `export VTK_DIR=/opt/vtk/lib` and `export VTK_DBG_DIR=/opt/vtk-dbg/lib` inside my `.bashrc`. As mentioned in the question when I echo the variables, they get printed. I also **start Qt Creator from the terminal**. I do that for my `ROS` setup. It uses `cmake` (where btw the mentioned variables DO work) so I can't exactly compare the two 1 to 1.